# using a single celery with multiple python daemons

Tags: celery

I have "project" written in Python with multiples components: there are several distinct Pyramid and Twisted apps running.

We're looking at using Celery to offload some of the work from Pyramid and Twisted.  Just to be clear, we're looking at one Celery instance / config, that handles the work for multiple Pyramid and Twisted apps.

All the info I found online covers multiple Celery for one or more apps; not one Celery for multiple apps.  Celery will be doing 4-5 functions that are common to all these apps.

Are there any recommended strategies / common pitfalls for this sort of setup, or should we be generally fine with having a standalone `celery_tasks` package that all the different projects import ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is distributed system. By the definition it doesn't matter from where you call the tasks as long as they get executed by a worker and the caller is able to fetch the results.

You should be fine with both projects configured properly to sending tasks and receiving results. One shared module with common tasks is going to be just fine.

Shared workers should import only that module.